# C# generics: Can you convert <T> ToString?

Tags: c#, variables, generics, types, field

Quick one here~
I want to convert < T >  ToString so I can replace the variable with that type~

```
public void ChangePanel<T>(T Action){

    FieldInfo Field = T.GetField(T.toString);
    Field.SetValue(SomeObject, Action);
}
```

Also please let me know if there is a better way to do this!!

Edit: FYI the variables in *SomeObject* have the same name as type

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: T.toString? maybe try T.ToString()

Comment: Yes, that should work

Comment: T is a type, not an object

Comment: This method is meant to change my static (ActionPanel) class, whatever Action I give it I would like to replace the corresponding variable in the (ActionPanel) singleton~

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`typeof` Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) to get a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) instance, and the [Type.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) to get the type's name.

```
public void ChangePanel<T>(T action)
{
    Type typeOfObject = someObject.GetType();
    Type typeOfAction = typeof(T);

    FieldInfo field = typeOfObject.GetField(typeOfAction.Name);
    field.SetValue(someObject, action);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Although couldn't I just remove the generic and just use "Action.GetType().Name" ??

Answer (score 8):

Yes. `ToString()` is defined on the `object` class which everything derives from so I would expect you can call it on any type `T`. However, you need to call it on the parameter itself, not the type, so rather than doing `T.ToString()` you should be doing `Action.ToString()`. If you want to get the name of the type then you should use reflection rather than `ToString`.

Also, the reflection options are either;

```
 typeof(T).Name
```

or

```
 Action.GetType().Name
```

Comment: @Silvermind T is a type parameter. It isn't the instance, if I had say a `Person` class with an overloaded `ToString()` method that returned the person's first and last name calling `ToString()` on `T` would not have the desired effect of returning the first and last name, I would have to call it on the instance which is what Valamas is saying. T is in fact a type. Generics in C# require you to specify the type within the `<>` symbols (it can actually be inferred in some cases, but that's the basic idea).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the name of a generic type, then you can simply call `typeof(T).Name`:

```
public static string GetGenericTypeName<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ToString` method is a method, so you need parentheses to call it, and the case is important for identifiers:

```
FieldInfo Field = (typeof T).GetField(Action.ToString());
```

The `GetField` is a method of the `Type` class, so you need `typeof` to get the `Type` object for the `T` generic type.